# Livewire/Alpine Dom template not updating

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

first time using Livewire with Alpine and its a real pain to debug. Alpine console errors are so vague, is there anyway to make them more specific and verbose?

I digress.

I'm updating an array on livewire component which, when not empty, should be showing in the DOM. Everything works and when viewed in the console i can see that the changes are being made. inside the console everything is happening as it should. The trouble is, nothing i happening in the browser!

```
<div x-data="{ ...data() }" class="overflow-hidden wrapper w-full ">
    <div class="flex justify-end w-full relative coins-container space-x-6">
        <input id="search-toggle" type="search" pclass="block w-full bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:shadow text-gray-700 font-bold rounded-lg pl-12 pr-4 py-4 shadow-xl" wire:model.debounce.750ms="searched_term"  />
    </div>
    @if($filtered_variable)
    <template>
        <div class="mt-1 wrapper">
            <div id="search-content" class=" w-full text text-gray-600 rounded-lg overflow-y-auto bg-white shadow-xl" style="max-height: 500px;">
                <div id="searchresults" class="h-auto w-full mx-auto">
                    @foreach ($filtered_variable as $index => $value)
                    <h1 x-text="{{$value['title']}}"></h1>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
    @endif
</div>



Class Searchbar extends Component
{
    public $first_array;
    public $searched_term;
    public $filtered_array;

public function mount()
{
    $db_content = Stuff::where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('thing', false)
            ->orWhereNull('thing');
    })
        ->with('variable_eg')
        ->get();

    

    $this->first_array = $db_content;
    $this->searched_term = '';
    $this->filtered_array = [];
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.searchbar');
}
public function updated($name, $value)
{

    if (empty($this->searched_term)) {
        return '';
    }
    $this->filtered_array = array_filter($this->first_array, array($this, 'filter'));


public function filter($element)
{
    $title = strtolower($element['title']);
    if (strpos($title, $this->searched_term) !== false) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

inside the console I can see that my alpine/livewire component is receiving the filtered_value just as expected. But nothing is happening on the browser. How can I force rerender?

Comment: updated to show Livewire

Comment: which alpine version do you use? use the latest one (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.8.0/dist/alpine.min.js) , it has proper error messages for debugging

Comment: @Irfan currently using 2.4.1. HAs it been updated since then?

Comment: @BenKemp yes, of course, the latest version is 2.8.0

Answer (score 0):

To update (refresh/rerender) your component you can use a listener

```php
protected $listeners = ['refreshComponent' => '$refresh'];
```

Then when the `refreshComponent` event is emitted, it will refresh the component without running any other actions.

There is a [Github discussion](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/discussions/1023) in the Livewire repo describing this.

**Regarding your `updating` and `filter` methods (just as a hint):**
There are also special methods like `updatingFoo`, `updatedFoo` that run before/after an item `foo` is updating. See the [Lifecycle Hooks](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/lifecycle-hooks).